# Getting reviews of a web-application

Tags: web-applications, web2py

I am totally new to web-development and I just created my first app with my teammates. I am just wondering if you can give me some feedback. The application is still in process. We still have to code a help and forum page, but the app itself is done.

https://wwu39.pythonanywhere.com/prostudy/default/index

I need to get some reviews for an upcoming presentation that I am having on this app. Use it if you can
There are still some bugs that I need to fix
The idea is very simple, insert a set of tasks that you normally do
like facebook
anime,
study,
eat,
sleep,
categorize them according to its usage
whether it is productive, non productive or necessary
choose the task that you will do and start the timer once you are done stop and switch to another task